# Messenger and a cloud storage service with a Linux app too

Tags: windows, android, linux, chat, cloud-storage

I am currently using [keybase.io](https://keybase.io/).
This software puts together an instant messenger  and a cloud storage service, however, after the Zoom acquisition, it seems to be a dead project. So I want to look for something different.

Keybase killer features are:

1. Messenger + cloud storage.
2. A Linux app too (beyond the usual Android, etc.).
3. It does not require sharing a mobile number with everyone.
4. A CLI app.

I understand, the CLI app can be hard to find, then what I really need is just a convenient way to invite several people without manually typing each email/username.

I can pay, for some of these features, but it should be free for the people I invite.

To me, it seems so obvious that you want to talk with the group whom you share project files with, but sharing apps do not come with a messenger usually.

Comment: Just to make sure - Google Drive + Chat is not an option for you?

Comment: You could go with Nextcloud (self-host or use a provider to host your instance) – which without additions already does your cloud storage and more. Add the [Nextcloud Talk](https://nextcloud.com/talk/) app, and you have video conferencing plus messenger. Supporting apps are available for many systems, including Linux and Android. Many [more apps available to integrate with the server](https://apps.nextcloud.com/), available to all its users. Would that fit your needs?

Comment: @Sebastian: is there an app which sits in the tray icon, where I get notifications?

Comment: @Izzy: Where is the Nextcloud Talk for Linux?

Comment: In all the web browsers available for Linux? You don't need a native application for most of the nextcloud things. For convenience, there's a Nextcloud desktop app, and one for file sync as that's better done "natively". Several other Linux (and cross-platform) applications support Nextcloud natively – I e.g. have my calendars and address book available in Evolution, then there's QOwnNotes, and more. For notifications, I don't know (never used that); I vaguely remember there is, but cannot point you to it. You could even use it for Android cloud notifications with UnifiedPush.

Comment: @Izzy: A) Can you give me the link to download the talk app you mentioned, please? B) How do I know there's a new message without notifications in the tray area? C) Just installed Nextcloud desktop, but it's the usual Dropbox-like app, with no chat/IM.   Thanks for your patience.

Comment: A) https://f-droid.org/packages/com.nextcloud.talk2/ B) your browser can take care of that (enable notifications there) C) told you so; chat etc. is done in the browser, the desktop app is mainly for file sync etc.

Comment: Google products usually run in the browser, and they can send notifications.

Comment: @Sebastian: but I have to keep the browser and the browser tab always open, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://rocket.chat/ it can be usefull for you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Can you explain how so? How does RocketChat meet the requirements, and what makes it recommendable? Just a link is not considered an answer here, see [our discussion on answer quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185). Thanks for your contribution – and thanks in advance for your coming **[edit]** to fill the gaps :)

Comment: Nice app Antek, how do you invite a group of  people?